# Distribution with random parameter

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

[image]

This is an extract from text book, I need help understanding how to integrate the function at line 3. Point me in the right direction please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that the expression is just the pdf of [gamma distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution) with parameter $\beta=2$ and $\alpha=k+1$.

$$f(x; \alpha, \beta)=\frac{\beta^{\alpha}}{\Gamma(\alpha)}x^{\alpha-1}e^{-\beta x}.$$

Hence it integrates to $1$.